# Issues with looping through files in directory to extract data in PDFs and placing them in CSV in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pdf

I was attempting to write code using the csv, os, and PyPDF2 packages to extract text from numerous pdf files within a directory and then place the data in a csv. The following code illustrates my efforts (it runs but provides no output):

```
import PyPDF2

import csv

import os

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
     if filename endswith('.pdf'):
     pdfFileobject = open(filename, 'rb')
     pdfUnderstander = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)
     numberpages = pdfUnderstander.getNumPages()
     increment = 0
     text = ""
          while increment < numberpages:
          pdfPage = pdfUnderstander.getPage(increment)
          increment += 1
          text += pdfPage.extractText()
          print(text)
```

I have not also quite gotten to the part yet for csv because of the failure of the part above to work, but would like some advice on how that could be stored as well.

Comment: Hi, it is not clear how your code is indented, please can you include this in the question as this will help others understand your code.

Comment: Think its now indented. Sorry about that (it's my first time using this site).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are making mistake while extracting filename.

Mistakes you are making: - Variable Name.

```
**pdfFileobject** = open(filename, 'rb')
pdfUnderstander = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(**pdfFileObject**)
```

Try this code:

```
path = r'Dir contains PDFs'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.split(".")[-1] == 'pdf':
        print(filename)
        pdfFileObject = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb')
        pdfUnderstander = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)
        numberpages = pdfUnderstander.getNumPages()
        increment = 0
        text = ""
        while increment < numberpages:
            pdfPage = pdfUnderstander.getPage(increment)
            increment += 1
            text += pdfPage.extractText()
        print(text)
```

Comment: So you would recommend using the absolute pathname in this case?

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately, when i run the code, i still don't get the extracted text to print in my shell. I am curious as to why both are codes are not able to produce a printed output. Do you think there is a reason behind that because of maybe the while loop?

Comment: No I do not recommend absolute pathnames. You can use the relative path.

Comment: I think the issue is with pdfFileReader.... It is not able to extract text from pdf. Try this with clean pdf files. individually.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by clean pdf files? I was able to earlier write code with individual pdf files and have it to work. That being said, I need to access maybe hundreds of files stored within a directory. That will not be possible to do on an individual basis.

Comment: Clean pdf means easily readable by a machine. (Create one Word file with some text file and export it as pdf and try the code on that file.)

Comment: Is this code is printing filenames for you??
 **print(filename)**

Comment: No. It just gives no output. What's frustrating is that it clearly works for each pdf in question if i do them seperately so it has to be something with either the directory code or the loop.

Comment: Try once with absolute path. And see the results?

Comment: You got the results?

Comment: Nope. Used r to get rid of the Unicode error and still causes an issue.

Comment: It just gives no output which worries me because it compiles but gives no output.